# How to redirect errors to home page in MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get my website when I'm on the root page to automatically default back to the homepage if I type in a bad URL, how do I do this in MVC?

I'm just learning MVC and can't figure this out... I have this:

```
namespace DvdApplication
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dvd", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that using web.config or HandleError Attribute:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="401" path="/Error/Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Generic" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="501" path="/Error/Generic" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

PS: note that should exist a controller "Error" and actions "Forbidden", "NotFound" and "Generic".

or

[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(SqlException), View = "DatabaseError")]]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(NullReferenceException), View = "LameErrorHandling")]]

more info:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1